# Copy image and paste to OCR

Tags: windows, ocr

Running Win 7. Is there OCR freeware that easily allows copy of a picture and paste into the conversion program. I have no scanner at this time. Want to convert stored images.

Answer (score 1):

Google docs will run OCR on images uploaded as files or pdfs. It's not copy paste but it's free and pretty good.

If you don't have a pdf creator program, install PDF Creator from sourceforge to create the pdfs that you'll then upload to google docs.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you have Office installed?  OneNote will do this.

Comment: Wow. Very cool. Copy and paste picture, right click on picture, choose "Copy Text from Picture" option.